# Check if remote host is able to resolve an internal url in Ansible

Tags: dns, ansible

Due to network architecture, I have a need to check if the remote host I am running an Ansible play against is able to resolve specific internal URLs.  The Ansible server and the remote host use different DNS servers (remote host using an internal DNS server), so I need to make sure that the URLs resolve there.

I have looked at using a lookup such as:

```
- name: Simple A record (IPV4 address) lookup for example.com
  debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', 'example.com.')}}"
  delegate_to: < remote server>
```

but the documentation states that the host running the looking will require dnspython library, which I will not have on the remote host.

So besides doing something though shell or command modules and registering the stdout.  Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: [**All** lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html) (see first paragraph) are interpreted on the ansible control machine.  So this will not fulfill your requirement. I do not know any other way at the moment than firring an `nslookup` from the command/shell. Or (provided that your controller has network access to remote configured dns...) you could read the DNS servers from the remote and use the dig lookup from the controller targeting the other DNS. But that is not really KISS.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Zeitounator.  I guess there is no other choice than going with shell.

Comment: Not that I know off at present time as indicated above unless you want to try the harsh path that might end up not working anyway. I'd KISS if I were you.